# How to move file from one server to another server

Tags: asp.net

How to move file from one server to another server? Plz help
When user uploading the excel file i am moving that file to another server
this is the code i am using.....

```
string destFilename = @"\\192.168.1.2" + @"\\xyz\\xyz1\\" +
    fileName + "";
System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, destFilename);
```

Comment: Seriously, not enough information to go on. My advice, given such limited info, is to copy it to a USB stick, transfer that to the other server, and copy back on.

Or, you could expand on your question and make our life, and yours, so much easier.

Comment: Please check my edit, your code was not properly written so I added another quote where it made most sense. Edit if I got it wrong.

Comment: I think he's asking how to programaticly copy a file from one server to another.  Does System.IO.File.Copy work with UNC paths??

Answer (score 2):

Your destination path is wrong it would turn out to be

```
\\192.168.1.2\\sabre\\Mapping Rules Upload\\<filename>
```

you need 1 slash in each directory seperator

You either need

```
string destFilename = @"\\192.168.1.2" + @"\sabre\Mapping Rules Upload\" + fileName + "";
```

or if you remove the "@" then you need to escape each "\" with another "\"

```
string destFilename = "\\\\192.168.1.2" + "\\sabre\\Mapping Rules Upload\\" + fileName + "";
```

The @ sign just saves you escaping chars that require escaping in a string!

EDIT: I am presuming that in your code fileName and filePath are set correctly!

HTH

OneSHOT

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but here is a sample that transfers files using webservices
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5805105.html